# How do I create my own cmake target with pkg-config settings?

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

My project is `shared` library, and I would like to create installation target with settings for `pkg-config`.

Currently it builds by only one, very simple rule:

`add_library(mylib SHARED src/mylib.cxx)`

And here I'm stuck with further configuration because every installation rule should be dependent on the preconfigured installation paths and flags. To keep it simple, let's say, the target will be installed to `include and lib` directories and preconfigured `.pc` rules will be something like `-lmylib -I/...include -L/....lib`

How can I configure cmake's `installation` targets with `pkg-config` support ? I guess it does not have builtin support of `pkg-config` and I need your help to find a proper solution.

Comment: `I guess it does not have builtin support of pkg-config and I need your help to find a proper solution.` - Yes, CMake has no builtin support for generate `.pc` files for the projects. Common way for such things is creating a "template" file, and transform it to `.pc` one with [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/configure_file.html) command. See e.g. this blogpost: http://dailycommit.blogspot.ru/2016/10/how-to-generate-pkg-config-file-with.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake can interoperate with pkg-config in both directions, though it's a little bit clunky.

[`FindPkgConfig`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) allows you to find and use libraries using their pkg-config files.

To have cmake generate a pkg-config file for your own library, you'll have to use [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) and have a template pkg-config file.

Comment: `configure_file` documentation was first what I found before asking .. unfortunately it does not help

Comment: As an earlier commenter noted, an example of using it for your situation exists [here](https://dailycommit.blogspot.co.uk/2016/10/how-to-generate-pkg-config-file-with.html)